# Can't run Spring Boot JAR file with specific profiles

Tags: java, spring-boot

Like the image I've attached, I can run my JAR file with command 'java -jar', but it doesn't work when I add a spring.profiles.active config, and I can't get any infomation in my console.

[image: screen shot]

Comment: Check the port is not used

Comment: Use `java -jar <your-jar> --spring.profiles.active=demo` instead. Also make sure that there is no `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE` environment property set or that other `application.properties` specify an `spring.profiles.active` property.

Comment: @M.Deinum same result compare to -Dspring.profiles.active

Comment: @YCF_L, I'm sure the port is not used

Comment: Then there is something else overwriting those properties, chekc your `bootstrap.properties`, `application.properties` (or YAML whichever you use) or the environment.

Answer (score 1):

Please try it as below:

```
java -jar service-app-1.7.44.jar -Dspring.profiles.active=demo
```